# Rotation changing UIImageView frame. How to avoid this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have two sliders - one for changing image size and one for rotating this image. My imageview is 60x60. The problem is that I rotate the image using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation, but when I try to resize it after that (like, from 60x60 to 65x65 using the slider), it acts weirdly - the frame of the image view has changed like 80x2. How can I avoid this? Here is my code for the slider that resizes the image:

```
-(IBAction)imageSliderAction:(UISlider *)sender
{
    NSUInteger value = sender.value;
    float oldCenterX = logoImageView.center.x;
    float oldCenterY = logoImageView.center.y;
    newWidth = value;
    newHeight = value;
    CGRect frame = [logoImageView frame];
    frame.size.width = newWidth;
    frame.size.height = newHeight;
    [logoImageView setFrame:frame];
    logoImageView.center = CGPointMake(oldCenterX, oldCenterY);
}
```

And here is the code for my rotating slider:

```
-(IBAction)rotationSliderAction:(UISlider *)sender
{
    NSUInteger angle = sender.value;
    if (sender.value >= 1)
    {
        CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle / 180.0 * 3.14);
        [logoImageView setTransform:rotate];
    }
    if (sender.value <= 0 )
    {
        CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( (360 + sender.value) / 180.0 * 3.14);
        [logoImageView setTransform:rotate];
    }
}
```

How can I avoid autochanging frame's width and height when rotating? Because after that I can't resize the image correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [UIView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5)

> Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the
>   value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

If you want to change the size of view that has nontrivial transform you should do that by changing its bounds property (view's center will remain the same so you won't need any extra logic to maintain its position):

```
[logoImageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,sender.value, sender.value)];
```

Comment: Problem solved! I knew that it is something with the bounds property, but didn't know exactly what to do. Thank you, my friend.